# I need help arranging the elements for my minimal password generator

Tags: buttons, placement, minimalist, rearranging

Here is the website right now: [apasswordgenerator.website](http://www.apasswordgenerator.website/)

So there are 3 elements:

- A generate button
- two trackbars to change the settings
- three passwords that are generated

Right now I have the two trackbars hidden until the "Customize" button is pressed (not all users want to customize their passwords, please tell me if this is bad practice).

I'm just not sure what the best way to arrange them is. I initially had the trackbars on top, button in the middle, and passwords on the bottom. This makes sense but the page became so tall that the user had to scroll. I wanted this app to be very minimal and I wanted to avoid making the user scroll. I also wanted to be sure that the document size doesn't change if any elements change.

I feel stuck and I'm not sure what to do. What do you guys think is best? Also if you have any other feedback on the site, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Comment: This comment is more about your technique then about UX: How large is your dictionary? It seems that passwords with a short length (your default setting) will generate words very repetitive. You should also take a look into `RandomSource.getRandomValues()` to generate strong random values. Maybe it's worth discussing this over at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I had originally: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPRJs.png

And here is what I decided to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIFxd.png

This way, there is a divide between the "action elements" and the results.